# Obtaining a rough upper bound of the size of std::string

Tags: c++, c++17

I consider using C++17's `std::variant` with the following types:

- 1 byte: `bool`;
- 4 bytes: integer and floating value;
- 2x 4 bytes: integer and floating value;
- 3x 4 bytes: integer and floating value;
- 4x 4 bytes: floating value;
- `std::string`.

The C++ standard, unfortunately, does not specify the implementation of `std::string`, but merely describes the interface and associated behavior of the class. Is it, however, possible to obtain a sort of rough upper bound of its size for the set of most commonly used compilers (MVC++, Clang, GCC, icc, etc.)? I am not really concerned with an exact upper bound, but I rather want to have an idea of the size compared to the already largest type of 16 bytes. I guess that a pointer could suffice to implement `std::string`, but due to the short string optimization, the size can be much larger?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this piece of code on the compiler explorer, and select various compilers:

```
#include <string>

size_t size()
{
  return sizeof(std::string);
}
```

https://godbolt.org/g/NTWsuk

For example, a possible result is:

```
size():
        mov     eax, 32
        ret
```

Meaning the size of `std::string` is 32 bytes.

Answer (score 2):

The usual implementation for `std::string` has three pointer-sized objects in it, so it would be *12 bytes* on 32-bit architectures and *24 bytes* on 64.

However, some implementations add debug features or things like that and are about 4 pointers in size. I haven't seen anything other than these two options on the common platform/compilers I work with (admittedly nothing exotic, though.)

Comment: You forget small-string optimization.

Comment: I know sometimes implementations increase their size to accommodate "larger" small strings, but other than that, I don't know what effect this has on string size.